# Use Elmah within Enterprise library

Tags: enterprise-library, elmah

Is it possible to hook in Elmah for Exception handling and exception logging within Enterprise library? Are they mutually exclusive meaning one or the other?

My plan is to use Enterprise library to get benefits such as caching, cryptography, etc. etc. But I am not sure if I could use ELMAH within Enterprise library.

Please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are already using EntLib, why wouldn't you use the Logging Block and the Exception Handling Block?

Answering your question, yes, you can plug-in other logging and exception handling providers.
For more details, see the [Microsoft Enterprise Library 5.0 Extensibility Hands-on Labs](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=13738).